# Using django class in a test with a mock patch

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mocking

Perhaps the question that I'm going to ask is very general and doesn't have a concrete answer. The case is that I spent some days trying to find an answer and I'm pretty lost. I would appreciate any kind of response or a reference to any book or manual that could help me.

I'm trying to recreate the Django authentication process using a test where I will check the user and password of my user.

The test function code is as follows.

```
import sys, os
import unittest, mock, kiss

from sqlite3 import connect, PARSE_DECLTYPES
from datetime import date
  
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.cred import credentials
from twisted.cred.error import UnauthorizedLogin

from ampauth.testing import DjangoAuthChecker

"""
Some irrelevant code for this question.
"""

    def test_GoodCredentials(self):
    creds = credentials.UsernamePassword(self.username, self.password)
    checker = DjangoAuthChecker()
    d = checker.requestAvatarId(creds)
```

Where `self.username` is the name of the user and `self.password` is the password.

The problem comes when I try to create the avatar of the user using the DjangoAuthChecker class.

```
import os

from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.python import failure, log
from twisted.cred import portal, checkers, error, credentials
from twisted.internet import defer

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DjangoAuthChecker():
    implements(checkers.ICredentialsChecker)
    credentialInterfaces = (credentials.IUsernamePassword,
    credentials.IUsernameHashedPassword)

    def _passwordMatch(self, matched, user):
        if matched:
            return user
        else:
            return failure.Failure(error.UnauthorizedLogin())

    def requestAvatarId(self, credentials, connection):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=credentials.username)
            return defer.maybeDeferred(
                check_password,
                credentials.password,
                user.password).addCallback(self._passwordMatch, user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return defer.fail(error.UnauthorizedLogin())
```

The previous code gives me the following error on the screen.

```
(.venv_test)sgongar@debian8-64bits-dev:~/Dev/client/protocol/tests$ python test_creds.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_creds.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ampauth.testing import DjangoAuthChecker
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/ampauth/testing.py", line 33, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So the question is, may I need a settings file for use a single django class?
I thought I could import a class without the need of a setting file.

How could I replace the setting file with a mock object?

---

#### Solved

Well, I added a few lines to configure the settings and I managed to avoid the error. Now I have another problem creating tables for users but will post the question on another page.

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True, 
                    DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test.db'),
                    'TEST_NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test.db'),}},
                    INSTALLED_APPS = ('django.contrib.auth',))

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password
from django.db import models
```

Comment: yes, any time you import from django you need a settings file

Comment: if you are making an actual django project (it looks like you are - you're using the `User` model) you should use the django test runner https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: @Anentropic 
Since I do not have access to the server installation, because I'm testing the operation of the client, planned to use something that simulate the behavior of the server. To use the Django testing, do I need access the server installation or is possible to simulate the responses with utilities Django testing?

Comment: yes, simulating is the best way - Django provides tools for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/